# Is there a way to autodetect when a display is disconnected?

Tags: nvidia, dell, display

I am running Ubuntu on a Dell Latitude with the latest Nvidia drivers. Basically what I want is when I disconnect my external display that everything goes back to the main one without having to change the config every time.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Have you tried `sudo xrandr --auto` after a change ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First install [**disper**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/disper/), then download [autorandr](https://raw.github.com/wertarbyte/autorandr/master/autorandr) and follow these instructions:

- When the external monitor is **undocked**, run the following command in terminal:

  ```
  auto-disper.sh --save undocked
  ```
- When the external monitor is **docked** and configured as you want (with Nvidia X Server Settings), run:

  ```
  auto-disper.sh --save docked
  ```
- Try:

  ```
  auto-disper.sh --change
  ```

  with docked and undocked monitor. It should detect the state and change the configuration.
- Finaly [make a keyboard shortcut](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/ubuntu-creating-custom-shortcut-keys/) for `auto-disper.sh --change`

I tried to make a script that run it every 3 seconds, so auto-dectection works, but use too much ressource.
Hope that can help!

Comment: This project has been merged into autorandr and is only available to keep links working. Please check autorandr.
http://github.com/wertarbyte/autorandr

Comment: *disper* is not in the 10.10 repositories.  It is available as a ppa: https://launchpad.net/~disper-dev/+archive/ppa

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of Nvidia Twinview on Linux. The open source driver will work as expected (though you'll lose 3D acceleration and Compiz).

Answer (score 1):

I'm in about the same situation. I use a laptop which is sometimes connected to my external monitor. When it is, I usually want to use only this monitor (because I have it hooked up to an external keyboard & mouse also).

What I found, is that if you have a file called *.xprofile*, it is called every time the display is initialized (by X.org?). [Here](http://pastebin.com/fD6YNzbK) is the contents of my file. As you can see, I adapted it from [here](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2#Now_automate_it_on_login).

What you should do is save it to *~/.xprofile* and then make it runnable (*chmod +x .xprofile*). Check how your internal and your external monitors are called - do this by running *xrandr* with no arguments. Mine are *VGA1* and *LVDS1* respectively. The last thing is to set the EXTERNAL_RES variable to the native resolution of your external monitor.

Now on boot up, the connected monitor will be used if it is connected. The tricky part is automation (such as removing the cable while Ubuntu is running). I haven't found a very good solution for this, but it seems that switching to a virtual console and back does the trick (Ctrl-Alt-F1 and then Ctrl-Alt-F7). It's a bit quicker than cycling through all the possibilities with the Fn key (which also sometimes messes up the display).

Answer (score 1):

Use [disper](http://willem.engen.nl/projects/disper/). After installing it, you may want to create two shortcuts:

1. To switch to extrnal display at max resolution: CTRL+E --> `disper "max" -S`
2. to go back to PRimary display : CTRL+P --> `disper "max" -s`

Answer (score 0):

You can always just press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> after disconnecting the monitor. That will probably change it back.

Comment: That doesn't work on my computer. The FN keys don't do anything. Do you know what could be?

Comment: @Diego for me just using F8 worked fine. without using the function key in conjunction.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic detection would be cool. Meanwhile I found this blog post which shows how to bind a key to a provided script that toggles between displays. It works pretty well for me. It would be nice if Ubuntu provided something like this out of the box.

http://ninetynine.be/blog/2010/05/quick-workaround-for-missing-switch-display-key-or-lcdcrt-key-on-ubuntu/