# Twinview on Gnome when monitor is unplugged

Tags: gnome, xorg, nvidia, twinview

i have a macbook pro which is often connected to a monitor, twin view on gnome works pretty well, but a problem arises when i disconnect the monitor, any window that resided on that workspace is no longer available.

another issue is when i start my computer when a monitor is not present, because xorg.conf file has the monitor configuration in it, my mouse pointer often disappears in the other monitor's virtual space, as if it is currently plugged,

osx deals with this issue elegantly by refreshing the display every time a plug in/out occurs,

is there anything similar that can be done in linux ?

```
> xrandr --auto
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

> xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 3200 x 1080, current 3200 x 1080, maximum 3200 x 1080
default connected 3200x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   3200x1080      50.0*
```

my first monitor is a macbookpro 5.5 13 inch display, and the second is a 24 inch display working at 1980x1024 (1080p) resolution

Comment: Would be good to know your Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 1):

This usually works out of the box on Ubuntu, but there could be a problem with this specific hardware. In this case executing `xrandr --auto` from the terminal should disable the disconnected monitor.

Comment: The problem is that with twinview nvidia doesn't actually report as 2 seperate screens. And if you do have seperate screens (read Xinerama) then randr isn't supported.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7292/is-there-a-way-to-autodetect-when-a-display-is-disconnected). In short, get `disper` from [its PPA](https://launchpad.net/~disper-dev/+archive/ppa) and consider using [auto-disper](https://github.com/wertarbyte/autorandr) as explained in that answer. Quoting the instructions from there:

- First, when the external monitor is **undocked**, run `auto-disper --save undocked`
- Then, when the external monitor is **docked** and configured as you want (with Nvidia X Server Settings), run `auto-disper --save docked`
- Try `auto-disper --change` with docked and undocked monitor. It should detect the state and change the configuration.
- Finaly make a keyboard shortcut with `auto-disper --change`

Thanks, [Vinços](https://askubuntu.com/users/4926/vincos) and [belacqua](https://askubuntu.com/users/8844/belacqua)!

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu 10.10

- Open `gconf-editor`
- Navigate to **apps** -> **gnome_settings_daemon** -> **Plugins** -> **xrandr** (/apps/gnome_settings_daemon/plugins/xrandr)
- Untick active

Answer (score 0):

You could try to disable xrandr by doing the following:

open **dconf-editor**

navigate to **/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/xrandr**

untick **active**

Good luck to you!