# Automate Twinview

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, twinview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to autodetect when a display is disconnected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7292/is-there-a-way-to-autodetect-when-a-display-is-disconnected)

My question is basically [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7292/is-there-a-way-to-autodetect-when-a-display-is-disconnected), but that's rather old now, and desktop Linux is changing fast.

I have a laptop with NVidia graphics (GeForce 9800M GS), the proprietary drivers, and Ubuntu 11.04 (using Unity).

Can Twinview be automated so that when I disconnect my external monitor, it's automatically disabled? The reserve would be nice as well, but the first is more important.

Answer (score 1):

Not much of an answer but that answer there might still be valid. Personally, I make use of the [disper indicator](http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2011/06/disper-indicator-easily-clone-or-extend.html) which makes it easy enough, plus allows me to manually disable the second monitor before playing games that don't support it or deal with it properly.